# what are the Documents Required for F1 Student Visa Application

Tags: student-visa

I applied for a usa study visa , my current employer will pay all study costs

from what i know , those letters what i need

1-salary certificate

2-No Objection Letter

3-FINANCIAL GUARANTEE

is ok to put all of them in one form ?

or must be 3 forms

sorry for my english

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ‘put all of them in one form’? https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/student-visa.html

Comment: i mean Write all these points ( salary certificate - no objection - financial guarante ) in one letter

Comment: Hamza, you don't need to submit letters with your application. Check the link provided above and bring with you any supporting documentation, which can be, but not limited to, letters from your employer. The Consular Officer might or might not ask for these documents during the interview.

Comment: @hamza alahdal It’s important that you actually include your papers with the application when you submit it. Don’t expect to just take the papers with you to the interview.